# How to specify the control argument of the loess R function using ryp2 in python?

Tags: python, r, loess

I am trying to call loess R function from Python using ryp2. I encountered the following error when I tried to specify the "control" argument in r.loess: 'SignatureTranslatedFunction' object has no attribute 'control'.

In R, I used

```r
S_fit <- loess(y ~ x, data = df, degree = 2, span = d, 
               control = loess.control(surface = "direct"))
```

which worked.

In my python code, I tried

```py
loess_fit = r.loess("y ~ x", data=df, degree = 2, span = d, control=r.loess.control(surface = "direct"))
```

The error message I got was

```py
AttributeError: 'SignatureTranslatedFunction' object has no attribute 'control'
```

I am confused by this error since loess function in R clearly has a control parameter for user to specify.
I also tried the following code

```py
loess_fit = r.loess("y ~ x", data=df, degree = 2, span = d, surface = "direct")
```

This line of code did't throw any error but there is no output of the loess.
If I don't specify the control argument, my code would run smoothly.

## Here AS is a pandas dataframe

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

x=AS["x"].values
y=AS["y"].values
x = robjects.FloatVector(list(x))
y = robjects.FloatVector(list(y))
df = robjects.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y})
loess_fit = r.loess("y ~ x", data=df, degree = 2, span = d, control=r.loess.control(surface = "direct"))
wv_vec= robjects.FloatVector(list(order["wv"]))
B1 =r.predict(loess_fit, wv_vec)
```

I hope there is a way for me to specify the control parameters. I am new to `ryp2` and any advice would be appreciated!

Update: I think

```py
loess_fit = r.loess("y ~ x", data=df, degree = 2, span = d, surface = "direct")
```

actually worked! No idea why it didn't work at the beginning. But I still don't understand why ryp2 cannot find the control parameters

Comment: `r.loess` looks like a function, are you sure that `r.loess.control` is what you should be calling? Also, it would help to see the errors raised by the two different statements that you posted.

Comment: Hi Daniele @DanieleGrattarola!  I assumed I should call r.loess.control since there is a loess.control function in R and I used this in my original R code (see the first code block), which worked fine. I also update the errors statements you requested in my post. Thank you